# How to change the color of a Column-chart created with Chartkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

Is it possible to change the color of a Column-Chart created with Chartkick ? I searched for it inside the Documentation but i could not find anything about it. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Google Charts, use the library option to change the color of the entire series.

```
<%= column_chart data, :library => {:colors => ["red"]} %>
```

There's not an easy way to change each bar in a single series at the moment.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above solutions they did not work.
The color option for chartkick should be in the below format to work.

`<%= column_chart @data, colors: [["#63b598", "#ce7d78", "#ea9e70", "#a48a9e", "#c6e1e8"]]  %>`

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

I think it might work like this:

```
  = column_chart(@data, library => { :series => { 0 => { color: "red" } }
```

Like this you can define that for each series.