# Chartkick column charts multiple colors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I'm using [chartckick](http://ankane.github.io/chartkick/) in my RoR project to generate charts, which works quite nice. (along with Google Charts).

I've created a [column chart](http://ankane.github.io/chartkick/#chart-3) with **only 2 bars** (male and female).

[image]

And now the client wants that each bar have different color? Is that possible?

I've seen this post - [How to change the color of a Column-chart created with Chartkick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179365/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-column-chart-created-with-chartkick) but it's more then half of year old and I'm hoping that there is a way now to specify more colors to the bars.

**Update**

My code looks like:

*Controller*

```
@followers_gender_count = Project.find(params[:id]).followers.group(:gender).count
```

*View*

```
<%= column_chart parse_gender_data(@followers_gender_count) %>
```

*Helper*

```
def parse_gender_data(data)
  gender_data = Hash.new
  gender_data[:male] = data[1]
  gender_data[:female] = data[2]
  ({ 'Male' => gender_data[:male], 'Female' => gender_data[:female] })
end
```

**Update 2**
- [Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/149)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [@buren's comment on GitHub](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/149#issuecomment-70431516) it seems that using a different JSON structure will invoke different colors on the `column_cart`.

---

I changed the output in the **Helper**:

```
def parse_gender_data(data)
  gender_data = Hash.new
  gender_data[:male] = data[1]
  gender_data[:female] = data[2]
  [{"name" => "Male","data" => {"Gender" => gender_data[:male]}},{"name" => "Female","data" => {"Gender" => gender_data[:female]}}]
end
```

---

And created the `chartkick.rb` **config** file (`config/initializers/chartkick.rb`), adding some *colors*:

```
Chartkick.options = {
  colors: ["#63b598", "#ce7d78", "#ea9e70", "#a48a9e", "#c6e1e8"]
}
```

---

Which outputs the desiring result:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The following also works. I didn't need any new files in initializers (no chartkick.rb file), this just worked by adding the following code to my helper file:

```
  def networth_data
    [
      {name: "Assets", data: {"NetWorth": 6979.53}}, 
      {name: "Liabilities", data: {"NetWorth": 10532.32}}
    ]
  end
```

And then in my html.erb i specified the colors and other options I wanted:

```
<%= column_chart networth_data, 
  colors: ["green", "#FF0000"], 
  library: {backgroundColor: "#FFF", height: 265} %>
```

...renders this chart:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [ColumnStyles](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#ColumnStyles)

```
   function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Visitations', { role: 'style' } ],
        ['2010', 10, 'color: gray'],
        ['2010', 14, 'color: #76A7FA'],
        ['2020', 16, 'opacity: 0.2'],
        ['2040', 22, 'stroke-color: #703593; stroke-width: 4; fill-color: #C5A5CF'],
        ['2040', 28, 'stroke-color: #871B47; stroke-opacity: 0.6; stroke-width: 8; fill-color: #BC5679; fill-opacity: 0.2']
      ]);
```

but take a look at the link there are some really cool stuff there

Comment: How to apply that code in ruby? I've updated the OP with my code.

Comment: @Vucko do where do you have the settings for the colors or style you want to use?

Comment: @Vucko take a look at https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/blob/master/lib/chartkick/helper.rb lines  (15-17) you can see that it takes 2 parameters `data_source`, and `options` as a hash so you could do `<%= column_chart parse_gender_data(@followers_gender_count, style_hash) %>`

Comment: I tried like this [comment on github](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/149#issuecomment-66792065) but it doesn't work. Also, I tried like `[['Male', 23, 'color:red'], ['Female', 123, 'color:green']]` but it also doesn't work. Can you make a working example/fiddle?