# RoR - Chartkick.js and Ratyrate (styling issues)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, chartkick, raty

With some coding and getting the ratyrate to work into chartkick.js - there are very minimal tutorials regarding styling changes.

The data is working into the bar graph as shown below;

HTML Setup for display:

```
        <div class="col-md-4">
                <%= bar_chart Review.group(:rating).count(:rating), colors: ["blue"],  discrete: true %>
                <p>Sum of each Review</p>
                <%=@review_total_each%>
                <p><%=@review_count%> Total Review count</p>

        </div>
```

[image: chartkick.js with data from ratyrate]

Main objective is to get it to look like this;

- have different colours per each rating number
- reverse order with 5 being at the top
- remove the bottom legend (only keep the left)
- remove the lines between the bars
- done need to worry about the average etc, only focussing on the colour changes to the bars

[image: expected design outcome]

I have read some tutorials although each review needs to become a unique data set and then you can complete colours.
([Chartkick column charts multiple colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27616283/chartkick-column-charts-multiple-colors))

But still having no success.

Any help or guidance will be appreciated.
(I can always update the question with requests)

Comment: did you solve it ?

Comment: @RareFever - wasnt able to complete updates with chartkick and move to google charts instead and this worked a lot better