# Chartkick column_chart different colors not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chart.js, chartkick

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/rubymine-code-insight-for-ruby-and-rails/) for setting up my charts using `Chartkick` and `Chartjs`. I wanted to change the colors of my datasets for my `column_chart` and tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27616283/chartkick-column-charts-multiple-colors) and it did change the default color, however, the same color still gets displayed for all columns.

I have this setup in my controller:

```
# detected_vehicles_controller (API)
  def by_total_count_per_vehicle_type
    query_params = { q: { 'detection_time_eq' => @date } }
    detected_vehicles = DetectedVehicle.group(:vehicle_type).search_by_params(query_params).count
    render json: parse_vehicle_type_data(detected_vehicles).chart_json
  end

  private

  def parse_vehicle_type_data(data)
    vehicle_type_datasets = []
    data.each do |key, value|
      dataset = {}
      dataset['name'] = key
      dataset['data'] = { key => value }
      vehicle_type_datasets << dataset
    end
  end
```

And set my colors in my initializer

```
# config/initializers/Chartkick.rb
Chartkick.options = {
    colors: ["#63b598", "#ce7d78", "#ea9e70", "#a48a9e", "#c6e1e8"]
}
```

These codes are triggered from the following view and helper:

```
# _graphs.html.slim (partial)
.ui.grid.stackable
  .sixteen.wide.column
    = viz_total_count_per_vehicle_type(@date)
```

```
# helper
  def viz_total_count_per_vehicle_type(date)
    column_chart by_total_count_per_vehicle_type_api_analytics_detected_vehicles_path(date: date)
  end
```

These codes generate the following script and chart:
[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I removed the config for colors that I set in my `config/initializers/Chartkick.rb` and tried to pass the `backgroundColor` in my `library` option in my helper but it didn't work.

```
# Helper
  def viz_total_count_per_vehicle_type(date, location)
    column_chart by_total_count_per_vehicle_type_api_analytics_detected_vehicles_path(date: date, location: location),
                 library: background_color
  end

  private

  def background_color
    {
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(75, 192, 192)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64)',
        'rgba(255, 205, 86)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255)',
        'rgba(201, 203, 207)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 2
    }
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a working solution for now though I don't think that it is the ideal one.

What I did was I removed the `colors` in the `options` that I have set in `config/initializers/Chartkick.rb` and passed it instead as I render the json in my controller. So my controller method looks like:

```
# detected_vehicles_controller (API)
  before_action :load_data

  def by_total_count_per_vehicle_type
    chart_data = @detected_vehicles.group(:vehicle_type).count
    render json: [{ data: parse_vehicle_type_data(chart_data),
                    library: background_color }].chart_json
  end

  private

  def load_data
    query_params = { q: { 'detection_time_eq' => @date, 'camera_camera_area_eq' => @location } }
    @detected_vehicles = DetectedVehicle.search_by_params(query_params)
  end

  def parse_vehicle_type_data(data)
    vehicle_type_datasets = []
    data.each do |key, value|
      dataset = {}
      dataset['name'] = key
      dataset['data'] = { key => value }
      vehicle_type_datasets << dataset
    end
  end

  def background_color
    {
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(75, 192, 192)',
        'rgba(255, 99, 132)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64)',
        'rgba(255, 205, 86)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255)',
        'rgba(201, 203, 207)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 2
    }
  end
```

So my chart now looks like:
[image]